# Canceling javascript requests in IE

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, browser

does anyone know how to handle and cancel javascript requests in IE?
Basically, i'm interested in such functionality for C# WebBrowser control.
The goal here is to handle javascript/ajax requests to internet and if request's URL match some filter then cancel it. Think of it as some sort if ads blocker. 
But any solution will be fine because i think i will be able to use it somehow in my project.
Or maybe you know how to do this with other browser/wrapper?
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is a "javascript request" and what happens when you "cancel" it?

Comment: What do you mean by "JavaScript request"? Are you referring to AJAX requests?

Comment: I'm hosting .NET WebBrowser control inside WinForms application.
Some sites load data from javascript/ajax code.
I want to be able to cancel those calls. But i don't know how to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to ajax calls then it depends how you make the call.  If you make the call using jquery for example then an example of how to cancel it is here:

[Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery)

If you make the call directly using and XmlHttpRequest object then see the abort method here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(VS.85).aspx

So basically you call the relevant kill/abort method,  and then the handler or error callbacks that you have attached to the ajax call should never be called.

If you want to block ajax calls in a WebBrowser control there seems to be a way, but it's a bit messy. See the later part of this discussion:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/c7c9a6f9-9875-4d8b-8c87-81f2c423fa6a

Basically you can modify the HtmlDocument concerned to take out the ajax calls in the first place.  However, it does seem to be the case you can't disable javascript for a given IE session (so not just for the one in the WebBrowser control),  it's a global setting.

Comment: I'm not doing those calls. Sites, that i load in WebBrowser control, do.

Comment: I think you're stuck then.  Apparently WebBrowser doesn't even let you enable/disable javascript (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/c7c9a6f9-9875-4d8b-8c87-81f2c423fa6a) so I can't see how you could intercept a javascript call in the WebBrowser control.

Comment: But should be some way. Take a look on IE 9 developers toolbar. It can handle them just like Firebug do.

Comment: I don't need to disable all javascript, just cancel those whose URLs match some filter.

Comment: Ok,  well then the proposed solution should work for you.  Edit the HtmlDocument to identify and remove or change those urls.

Comment: I don't understand what solution you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're referring to by "JavaScript Requests" but...  If you're using the Web Browser Control in .Net 3.5+ Framework, you could intercept the HTML sent to the control and scrape the JavaScript off, but that's fairly clugey.

If you're able to edit the JavaScript directly, you could overwrite the function.  So if the function has been written as:

```
var alertUser = function(){alert('Hello, silly user.');}
```

You could write `alertUser = function(){};` Which basically is setting it to an empty function so it won't error when it's called; but instead do nothing.

If you want a function to "cancel" you would just add a `return;`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that's not what i need.